# Multiplying a number from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiplication

So I am trying to multiply a number from a text file to a variable called `quantity` which is also a number but for example `3x5` , it would output `33333`, but I need 15, how do I fix this?

```
if GTIN=='86947367':
with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
    next(fp)
    next(fp)
    total1=quantity*int(next(fp))
    print(total1)
```

output:`33333`

Comment: I just ran your code and it seems to work fine. Other than some wrong indentation and a missing initial value for quantity.

Comment: how did you run my code without the text file ?!

Comment: I made one... Also llja is right if the quantity is a string then it will be displayed the number of times that the text file value int that you took in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, obviously, your `quantity` is as string `'3'` - and this gets multiplied by 5, giving `'33333'`. You need one more `int()` to convert the `'3'` to `3` :)